# Problem capacitor with Capacitor convertFileSrc

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Hi I use convertFileSrc from capacitor to get the size of the blob in order to upload videos on my application. It works fine for iOs but not on android. The blob size is always 0 because the file path seems to be wrong. I don't know how to solve this problem if someone has already encountered this problem please.

```
const test = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(f.fullPath);
```

Url :

```
http://localhost/_capacitor_file_/storage/emulated/0/Download/video.mp4 error 404
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the android version? Download folder is not accessible on Android 11+

Comment: On android 10+ I have all permissions  and AndroidExtraFilesystems property config with sd card, internal storage. I don't have any idea ... :( The pictures are working but file not... Before the migration with Cordova the access file worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the application tag in Android Manifest.xml solved this problem for me.

Comment: Hi, yes I found before see your message but thanks it's correct :)